# Provide rank number to a list containing sorted tuples in python

Tags: python

I have a `list` which contains `sorted tuples` `based` on `2nd element` of the tuple.

Sample list is as follows:

```
 [ ('not', 48),
 ('this', 47),
 ('which', 45),
 ('by', 45),
 ('as', 44),
 ('are', 42),
 ('will', 41),
 ('i', 40),
 ('but', 38),
 ('all', 38),
 ('with', 34) ]
```

I need to provide rank_number to each tuple as follows:

```
[ ('not', 48, 1),
 ('this', 47, 2),
 ('which', 45, 3),
 ('by', 45, 3),
 ('as', 44, 5),
 ('are', 42, 6),
 ('will', 41, 7),
 ('i', 40, 8),
 ('but', 38, 9),
 ('all', 38, 9),
 ('with', 34, 11) ]
```

I tried writing for loop and comparing the 2nd element among each other but not getting proper rank for instances wherever the 2nd elements are same.

The code which i tried is as follows:

```
sorted_rank_words = []
rank_number = 1
list1 = sorted_words
count1 = 0
count2 = 0

for x in sorted_words:
  r1 = list1.index(x)
  list1.pop(r1)
  for y in list1:
    if x[1] > y[1]:
        count1 = count1 + 1

    elif x[1] == y[1]: 
        count2 = count2 + 1

  if count1 > 0:
    sorted_rank_words.append(x+(rank_number,))
    rank_number = rank_number + 1

  elif count2 > 0:
    sorted_rank_words.append(x+(rank_number,))
    rank_number = rank_number + count2
  count1 = 0
  count2 = 0
```

Comment: Show us the code you've written!

Comment: @Elmex80s updated the post. Please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a new list of the updated items then you can do.

```
rank = 0
skip = 0
prev = None

res = []
for word, v in lst:
    if v == prev:
        skip += 1
    else:
        rank += skip + 1
        skip = 0

    res.append( (word, v, rank) )    
    prev = v
```

Or if you want to update your existing list then you can do.

```
rank = 0
skip = 0
prev = None

for i, (word, v) in enumerate(lst):
    if v == prev:
        skip += 1
    else:
        rank += skip + 1
        skip = 0

    lst[i] += (rank,)  
    prev = v
```

---

I really liked McGrady's original answer using `itertools.groupby` and wanted to make it work since it was a bit cleaner, so I've also added my updated version here.

```
from itertools import groupby

result = []
skip = 0
for rank, (_, g) in enumerate(groupby(lst, key=lambda xs: xs[1]), 1):
    count = -1
    for v in g:
        count += 1
        result.append(v + (rank + skip,))
    skip += count
```

Comment: Thanks. It gave the O/P as required. I am not sure whether i can use the 2nd method given by you as the list contains tuple so i can't update the list.

Comment: You can update the list itself, you just can't update a tuple. All it does is replace the old tuple with a new one.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
result=[]


tmp=0
rank=0
count=1
for i in tuples:
    if i[1]==tmp:
        result.append(i+(rank,))
    else:
        result.append(i + (count,))
    tmp=i[1]
    rank=count
    count+=1

print result
```

you will get

```
[('not', 48, 1), ('this', 47, 2), ('which', 45, 3), ('by', 45, 3), ('as', 44, 5), ('are', 42, 6), ('will', 41, 7), ('i', 40, 8), ('but', 38, 9), ('all', 38, 9), ('with', 34, 11)]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i tried your solution and it gave me same rank for elements where 2nd element is same but the last element got appended one extra time. ('which', 45, 17),
 ('by', 45, 17),
 ('by', 45, 18),

Comment: @PrashantVikramSingh It works for me,I just updated another way,try this.

Comment: It worked but can you pls explain a bit how it works. i mean the syntax. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This doesn't skip over ranks for duplicates. 3, 3, 5 and 9, 9, 11 is what OP has.

Comment: The ranking follows 1, 2, 3, 3, 5... because there is a double up (3rd) the following rank is 5th not 4th. If there was 1, 1, 1 then the following rank would be 4th not 2nd.

Comment: @StevenSummers I see.I forgot a `else`.

Answer (score 1):

Tuples are immutable so the best way to do this is to loop through the tuples and for each tuple create a new one with the rank added to the end of it.

```
rank = 1
for tuple in tuples:
    tuple = tuple + (rank,)
    rank += 1
```

That should work if I'm understand the problem correctly. You might need to adjust/compare rank based on what you want it to be.

Comment: Yeah i am aware of that. i created a new list after appending rank to the existing tuple but my problem is wherever the 2nd element is same the rank  should be same for them.

Comment: So when you start your loop try keeping track of the 2nd element. If your current one is equal to the previous one don't increment the rank.

Answer (score 1):

```

```
results = []
prevcount, prevrank = 0, 1
for idx, t in enumerate(inputs):
    # when the current count is similar to the previous one
    if t[1] == prevcount:
        # add rank to the tuple and append to the results list
        results.append(t + (prevrank,)) 
    else: 
        results.append(t + (idx + 1,))
    # update rank and count
    prevrank = idx + 1
    prevcount = t[1]
```

```

Notes: Iterate through the inputs list.  When the current count is similar to the previous one, we can make the rank to be the same as previous one and concat it to the tuple; then, append to the results list.  Otherwise, the rank is the position(starting at index 1) of the tuple in the inputs list.

Comment: Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I got this "shortened" solution :

after defining `base` as the array of tuples

```
b = [('',10e10)]+base[:]
r,s =[],[]
for x in range(len(b)-1):
    r+=[bool(b[x][1] - b[x+1][1])]
    s+=[(b[x+1] + (sum(r),))]
```

That will do it,

interestingly , I noted that is require 2 math operations on first "score" array:
differing, and integering , yet , I wasn't able to put it into one linear